# Why is fmt::format not accepting a string as an argument?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, c++20, fmt

I've successfully used the `fmt` library before, so I'm not exactly sure why I'm having this problem. First I'll show you the code that is producing an error:

```cpp
void Logger::AttachSink(const std::string & id, LogSink sink) {
    using namespace std::literals;
    auto id_found = sinks.find(id) != std::endl(sinks);
    if(!id_found) {
        sinks.insert(std::make_pair(id, sink));
        Info(
            fmt::format(
                "Sink \"{}\" Attached"s,
                id
            ) // This is the line where the error is apparently happening, and I'm assuming the `id` is the culprit for some reason.
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the build log (**NOTE**: I'm using VSCode as my editor and CMake to build the project using Visual Studio 2019's compiler):

```
[main] Building folder: [WORKSPACE]
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build [WORKSPACE]/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -- /maxcpucount:6
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde for .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[build] 
[build]   logging.cpp
[build] [WORKSPACE]\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\fmt\core.h(1073,9): error C2338: Cannot format argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types [[WORKSPACE]\build\drakeng\drakeng.vcxproj]
[build] [WORKSPACE]\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\fmt\core.h(1070): message : while compiling class template member function 'int fmt::v7::detail::arg_mapper<Context>::map(...)' [[WORKSPACE]\build\drakeng\drakeng.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               Context=fmt::v7::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v7::detail::buffer<char>>,char>
[build]           ]
[build] [WORKSPACE]\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\fmt\core.h(1259): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'int fmt::v7::detail::arg_mapper<Context>::map(...)' being compiled [[WORKSPACE]\build\drakeng\drakeng.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               Context=fmt::v7::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v7::detail::buffer<char>>,char>
[build]           ]
[build] [WORKSPACE]\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\fmt\core.h(1084): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v7::detail::arg_mapper<Context>' being compiled [[WORKSPACE]\build\drakeng\drakeng.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               Context=fmt::v7::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v7::detail::buffer<char>>,char>
[build]           ]
[build] [WORKSPACE]\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\fmt\core.h(1241): message : see reference to alias template instantiation 'fmt::v7::detail::mapped_type_constant<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,Context>' being compiled [[WORKSPACE]\build\drakeng\drakeng.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               Context=fmt::v7::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v7::detail::buffer<char>>,char>
[build]           ]
[build] [WORKSPACE]\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\fmt\core.h(1400): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned __int64 fmt::v7::detail::encode_types<Context,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,>(void)' being compiled [[WORKSPACE]\build\drakeng\drakeng.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               Context=fmt::v7::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v7::detail::buffer<char>>,char>
[build]           ]
[build] [WORKSPACE]\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\fmt\core.h(1834): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v7::format_arg_store<fmt::v7::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v7::detail::buffer<char>>,char>,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>' being compiled [[WORKSPACE]\build\drakeng\drakeng.vcxproj]
[build] [WORKSPACE]\drakeng\logging.cpp(24): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> fmt::v7::format<std::string,const std::string&,char>(const S &,const std::string &)' being compiled [[WORKSPACE]\build\drakeng\drakeng.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               S=std::string
[build]           ]
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

The errors make it sound like `fmt` doesn't have a `fmt::formatter<std::string>` specialization which doesn't sound right to me, so I've either misconfigured something, or not included a header or something. Frankly, I'm quite baffled. Once I have an answer, it'll probably be something silly knowing my luck. Anyway, thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: And yes I realize I could just use concatenization to combine the strings, but what if I wanted to make the formatted string more complex, surely this should be possible. Also, pretty sure I've done this exact thing with the `fmt` library before, hence why I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so apparently the error was not being caused by what I thought it was being caused by (Thanks, Visual C++ compiler error messages, super helpful! /s ). So to explain what was actually going on:

- `Logger::Info` calls a more generic function called `Logger::Log(LoggingLevel level, const std::string & message)`.
- `Logger::Log` also calls `fmt::format` inside of it to format up some additional information to save to the log.
- One of the arguments of that `fmt::format` call is the `level` which then needs to be converted to a string (and I chose to make a `ToString` function instead of making a `fmt::formatter` for it).
- The problem was the `ToString` function returns an `std::optional<std::string>` to "cleanly" handle invalid values. Well, apparently I forgot to call `.value_or` on the return value, and **THAT** was what was causing the error.

Unfortunately none of the error messages even mentioned anything to do with that line, so that was quite a few minutes/hours wasted.